# Unique value of object to use in section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, unique

I have a Class and I need to get genre object, put in an array, get unique value (because I will have many)
and use the array to populate section of a tableView.

I have the following code:

```
class Movie {
var name: String!
var plot: String!
var imageUrl: String!
var genre: String!

init(name: String, plot: String, img: String, genre: String) {

    self.name = name
    self.plot = plot
    self.imageUrl = img
    self.genre = genre




  }
 }


}

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}


var loadMovie = [Movie]()


let insertMovie = Movie(name: "Blow", plot: "Blow bla bla bla", img:     "", genre: "Action")
let insertMovie2 = Movie(name: "BLade", plot: "Blade bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Action")
let insertMovie3 = Movie(name: "Inside Out", plot: "Blow bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Kids")
let insertMovie4 = Movie(name: "Titanic", plot: "Blow bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Drama")

loadMovie.append(insertMovie)
loadMovie.append(insertMovie2)
loadMovie.append(insertMovie3)
loadMovie.append(insertMovie4)


let unique = NSSet(array: loadMovie.map { $0.genre })
```

unique returns the unique value ( Action, Drama, Kids), but when I try to get section:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return unique[section].genre

}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return unique.count

}
```

it doesn't work.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: check that, you may forgot to set delegate for uitableview

Comment: Hi, I don't think so, I've just put all code of viewController. It seems that all are set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering the movies by genre each time the table view is reloaded is quite expensive.

This is a solution using an array of header (genre) names and a dictionary containing a `[Movie]` array for each genre respectively.

```
var unique = [String]()
var loadMovie = [String:[Movie]]()
```

Add a method to insert the movies. The logic is:

• If the genre exists, add the movie for that genre to the `[Movie]` array in the dictionary.
• If the genre does not exist, add the genre to the `unique` array and the movie to the dictionary.

```
func insertMovie(movie : Movie) {
  let genre = movie.genre
  if unique.contains(genre) {
    loadMovie[genre]!.append(movie)
  } else {
    unique.append(genre)
    loadMovie[genre] = [movie]
  }
}
```

Now insert the movies

```
let movie = Movie(name: "Blow", plot: "Blow bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Action")
insertMovie(movie)
let movie2 = Movie(name: "BLade", plot: "Blade bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Action")
insertMovie(movie2)
let movie3 = Movie(name: "Inside Out", plot: "Blow bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Kids")
insertMovie(movie3)
let movie4 = Movie(name: "Titanic", plot: "Blow bla bla bla", img: "", genre: "Drama")
insertMovie(movie4)
```

The relevant data source and delegate methods are

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
  return unique[section]
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return unique.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  let genre = unique[section]
  return loadMovie[genre]!.count
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` populate the cells with

```
...
   let genre = unique[indexPath.section]
   let movie = loadMovie[genre]![indexPath.row]
   cell.textLabel!.text = movie.name
...
```

An alternative is an array of arrays

Comment: great works fine. I'm planning to store data with coreData, so this could be a right way to do so. thanks

Comment: One more thing.. If I have a data for genre as follow: "Action,Thriller" I need to fetch only the first in order to create section. What can I do?

Comment: Check if the genre string contains a comma. If yes, use the part before the comma, if no use the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

An update for Swift 4

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return unique[section]
    }

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return unique.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let genre = unique[section]
     return loadMovie[genre]!.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "basicCell", for: indexPath)
    let genre = unique[indexPath.section]
    let movie = loadMovie[genre]![indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = movie.name
    return cell
}
```